# App Engine - fail to navigate to other pages

Tags: google-app-engine

app.yaml

```
runtime: php81
entrypoint: serve role.php
env: standard

handlers:
- url: /logo.png
static_files: logo.png
upload: logo.png
```

role.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Buy On Behalf</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h1>Buy On Behalf</h1>
<img src="logo.png" alt="Buy On Behalf">
<a href="seller_mainpage.php" class="button">Seller</a>
<a href="buyer_mainpage.php" class="button">Buyer</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

seller_mainpage.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Buy On Behalf</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h1>Buy On Behalf - SELLER</h1>
<img src="logo.png" alt="Buy On Behalf">
<a href="seller_registration.html" class="button">Register</a>
<a href="seller_login.html" class="button">Login</a>
<a href="role.php">Back</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

currently, I could navigate to role.php, however, why could I not navigate to seller_mainpage.php when the button is clicked? The url above has already changed though but not the interface.